# Why does this while loop not execute properly

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a basic code that prompts the user for a list of numbers as separate inputs, that then identifies the largest and smallest number. If the user enters anything other than a number the code should return an "invalid input" message. The code seems to run through the two inputs once, but then the while input seems completely broken and I'm not sure where its going wrong.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

try:
    num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
    num1 = int(num1)
    largest = num1
    smallest = num1

    while True:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done" :
            break
        if num > largest:
            largest = num
        if num < smallest:
            smallest = num
        else: continue
except:
    print('Invalid input')



print("Maximum is ", largest)
print("Minimum is ", smallest)
```

Comment: `largest` and `smallest` have the same value as they're pointing to the same object.

Comment: You convert `num1` to an `int`, but you don't do the same for `num`.

Comment: Also, the `try` statement should probably be more targeted, protecting *each* call to `int` individually.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your exit condition of "done" and if the input is not "done" then convert the string to an integer.
Then all the if conditions would correctly and your while loop should run.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

try:
   num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
   num1 = int(num1)
   largest = num1
   smallest = num1

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" :
        break        
    num = int(num)
    if num > largest:
        largest = num
    if num < smallest:
        smallest = num
    else: continue
except:
    print('Invalid input')


print("Maximum is ", largest)
print("Minimum is ", smallest)
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'largest' is not defined`

Comment: I had corrected the while loop part. The rest code would be the same as the one in the question. (Edit: Replaced the code with an executable one)

Answer (score 0):

heres a simple way to do it:

```
lst = []
while True:
    try: 
        lst.append(int(input("enter a number: ")))
    except:
        break

print(f"max is {max(lst)}")
print(f"min is {min(lst)}")
```

```
enter a number: 10
enter a number: 22
enter a number: 11
enter a number: 22
enter a number: 4
enter a number: done
max is 22
min is 4
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other corrections:

```
largest = None
smallest = None

try:
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    largest = num1
    smallest = num1

    while True:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if str(num) == "done" :
            break
        if int(num) > largest:
            largest = num
        if int(num) < smallest:
            smallest = num
        else: continue
except:
    print('Invalid input')

print("Maximum is ", largest)
print("Minimum is ", smallest)
```

Comment: @Seydi, when you assign num to largest or smallest, please cast them to int.